# Fill array with contents of csv with php

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am trying to fill a array with a csv so each field is separate part of the array, when i have filled the array and echo it out it quite literally says array for every enter.

I have a feeling that once i sort the csvfull array that the sku might need to be in loop inside the main processing loop to.

```
$ocuk = fopen("ocuk.csv", "r");
while (($result = fgetcsv($ocuk)) !== false)
{
    $csvfull[] = $result;
}
  print_r ($csvfull[0][1]);
$sku="$csvfull[1]";
while (($csv = fgetcsv($ocuk)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if (false === empty(array_intersect($sku, $csv)))
            {
code to display the results from csv that match the $sku variable
            }
    }
```

What i need it to do is csvfull array to fill with the contents of the csv such i can then call it into the variable sku to do comparison in next part of the code.

EDIT example of what i mean

csv example

```
data,data2,data3,data4 etc
data10,data20,data30,data40 etc
```

the array would then be like this

```
$csvfull=array() would contain the below
array("data","data2","data3","data4");
array("data10","data20","data30","data40");
```

then when i call csvfull[1] it display data2 then would go onto data 20 etc

Comment: Yes `echo $csvfull[X];` shows an array because the values of the CSV line are split into an array. Use print_r or var_dump on it. Rest of your question / problem is quite unclear

Comment: I will try clarify the rest of the question, both print_r and var_dump causes it to give a white page

Comment: updated question with a example to better explain wha ti mean for csvfull and what i require it to do

Comment: Ok now i have only one problem left i have got the data to display but it displaying wrong. for example csv line one would be data1,data2,data3 instead of going into the array as such that it be array("data1","data2","data3"); it is instead making it go as array("data1 data2 data3"); so as such when i print it i get data1 data2 data3 without the commas, but i require it to only give data2 out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$csvfull` is a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension is the rows of the CSV, the second dimension is the columns. So `$csvfull[1]` is an array containing all the values from the second line of the file. To get the SKU, you need to drill down to the appropriate column, e.g.

```
foreach ($csvfull as $row) {
    $sku = $row[1];
    // Do something with $sku
}
```

If you want to get an array of all the SKUs, you can do:

```
$sku = array();
foreach ($csvfull as $row) {
    $sku[] = $row[1];
}
```

Comment: Ok this is display content but it only display the first character from the csv in field 0 , im going to update the question with a example

Comment: unfortunately this is not working :( but i have successfully got the data into the variable but now the problem is how it goes into the array variable

Comment: This should work. The first time `$sku` will be `data2`, the second time it will be `$data20`.

Comment: I've added to my answer, showing how you can get an array of SKUs, which you can then use with `array_intersect`.

Comment: ive worked out the problem your code works :) ill accept the answer the problem is the data going into the array i will create a new question for it, it only worked when i changed it to $row[0];

Comment: According to the data you posted, `$row[0]` will be `data`, `data10`, etc. That's not what you said you wanted.

Comment: ive explained it better in a new question as it is different issue to this one your answer fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
<?php 


        $ocuk = fopen('clientes.csv','r');
        $i=0;
        while(!feof($ocuk)){
            $values = fgetcsv($ocuk);
            if(empty($values[1] )){ // any index which is not empty to make sure that you are reading valid row.
                continue;}  

        $csvfull[$i] = $values;
    $i++;           
        }

        print_r($csvfull);

.
    fclose($ocuk);
```

Comment: This is doing the same it causing it to white page when print_r or display array all the time with echo

Comment: use print_r() after completion of while loop and see.

Comment: still causes a white page, updated question with example to better explain what i am meaning

Comment: what do you mean by this i can see the first and second array but another index with blank data is coming do you mean that array index 2.Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => data [1] => data2 [2] => data3 [3] => data4 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => data10 [1] => data20 [2] => data30 [3] => data40 ) [2] => )

Comment: still never worked but i have got it working so the data goes in and can be seen but only one problem exists as described in comment in question